# Как приказать isotope.js (v2) просто обновить состояние?

Tags: javascript, html

Уважаемое сообщество, здравствуйте! Прошу помощи, уже не знаю что и пробовать..
Есть сетка итемов на isotope js (v2).

```
<!-- Container -->
<div id="icontainer" class="isotope-container">
  <!-- Item -->
  <div class="isotope-item">
    <div class="sort">1</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Item -->
  <div class="isotope-item">
    <div class="sort">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сортируется она по содержимому вот этого <div class="sort">
Но в определенный момент я скриптом меняю это содержимое. Подставляю туда нужную цифру.
И тут мне бы хотелось чтобы isotope сразу актуализировал свое состояние. Пересортировал свои итемы.
Какой метод мне нужно вызвать чтобы это произошло?
Или я неправильно действую изначально?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден.

```js
$('#icontainer').isotope('updateSortData').isotope();
```